# How to send data to many Google Form via Http request?

Tags: http, google-sheets

My Google Form consist of 10 pages and I need to send data using mobile app via http to this Google Form. My url looks like

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1pn4CNQ7OwKce4K7ebb_2WZQ6PmFBf-5Qxp8zfdaedSw/formResponse?entry.1748727384=TestValue1&entry.1949164265=TestValue2&entry.750756026=page2submit=Submit
```

BUT. Since my google Form has more than 1 page, I see in response just data for 1st page. Other fields for other pages is empty. So how can I send data for more than 1 page?

Answer (score 0):

So, finally I figured out how to do it. We need to add "pageHistory=" attribute for example pageHistory=1,2,3 Each page has a unique pageHistory number, I found it using Mozilla Firefox web tools. (just see html-code)